# Polymer Dart @observable different behaviour

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In the following Polymer Dart code:

```dart
@observable Map hisMap = toObservable(new Map());    // Line 1
@observable String hisString = '';                   // Line 2
```

Why does Line 1 need `toObservable` and Line 2 doesn't need it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Line 1

If you don't use `toObservable` only changes to `hisMap` will be recognized. For example when you assign another map to `hisMap` but not changes to values inside the map.
With `toObservable` the content of the map is observed as well and adding, removing, replacing of items in the map produces change events.

#### Line2

The only way this value can change is when you assign another string to `hisString`. Strings are immutable, maps are not.